# Some Files Got Corrupted

Tags: android, corrupt

The power went down and on restart all files are showing these weird characters and message is saying about I am using wrong encoding.

[image]
[image]

The interesting thing is, the code is appearing like this only in Android Studio. If I open any of individual file with notepad, the code is just fine.

Comment: This error can be resolved by cleaning your project and deleting the cache files. See Praveen's answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I got into the same problem To fix this issue

First, try ***Invalidate caches and restart*** if it not works then delete **.gradle .idea** folders in the project directory and open the project again.

> Note: Take Backup of project folder before trying

Comment: actually this problem occured right after I delete .idea and .iml file. Then I did "Invalidated caches and restart". The result was another problem.